# Combine 2 events when document loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I bind 2 different events when the document loads?

I have a text field and a button. The function should be executed either when the button is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
       myFunction();
    });
});
```

or when Enter is pressed:

```
$("#id_of_textbox").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        myFunction();
    }
});
```

But how to combine both events?

Comment: do you mean do `keyup` when the button is clicked?

Comment: define `combine events`. It's not clear what you are asking or what the specific problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
       myFunction();
    });
    $("#id_of_textbox").keyup(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            myFunction();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your function to as many events as needed, here's one way...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(myFunction);
    $("#id_of_textbox").keyup(myFunction);
});


function myFunction(event) {
  if ((event.type === 'keyup') && (event.keyCode !== 13)) {
    return;
  }
  // process event here
}
```